# Emu8086 asterisk character simultaneous display?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've been working on my code and I just want to ask if how can I display asterisk simultaneously by row? I was making a triangle of asterisks, for example first row "*" second row "***" here's my code to understand.

```
org     100h   



mov     ax, 3
int     10h

mov     ax, 1003h
mov     bx, 0      
int     10h




mov     dl, 0   
mov     dh, 0   

mov     bl, 0   

jmp     next_char

next_row:
inc     dh
cmp     dh, 16
je      stop_print
mov     dl, 0

next_char:


mov     ah, 02h
int     10h




mov     bh, 0
mov     cx, 7
mov     ah, 09h
int     10h

inc     bl      ; next attributes.





; set cursor at (dl,dh):
mov     dl, 0  ; column.
mov     dh, 0   ; row.
mov     ah, 02h
int     10h        




mov dl, 10 
int 21h    
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h    
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h   
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h    
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h  
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h

mov dl, 08  
int 21h
mov dl, 08 
int 21h
mov dl, 13 
int 21h
mov dl, 00 
int 21h    

mov dl, 10        ;new line
int 21h   
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h    
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h 
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, 08  
int 21h
mov dl, 08 
int 21h
mov dl, 13 
int 21h
mov dl, 00 
int 21h    

mov dl, 10        ;new line
int 21h    
mov dl, ' ' 
int 21h    
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h    
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, 08  
int 21h
mov dl, 08 
int 21h
mov dl, 13 
int 21h
mov dl, 00 
int 21h  

mov dl, 10        ;new line
int 21h    
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h    
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h   
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h 
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, 08  
int 21h
mov dl, 08 
int 21h
mov dl, 13 
int 21h
mov dl, 00 
int 21h    








;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
mov     dl, 1  ; * column position.
mov     dh, 1   ;  row position.
mov     ah, 02h
int     10h     


mov     bh, 0
mov     cx, 6
mov     ah, 09h
int     10h

inc     bl    


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;                                      
mov     dl, 1  ; *** column position.
mov     dh, 2  ; row position.
mov     ah, 02h
int     10h     


mov     bh, 0
mov     cx, 6
mov     ah, 09h
int     10h

inc     bl      

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

mov     dl, 1  ; ***** column position.
mov     dh, 3   ; row position.
mov     ah, 02h
int     10h     


mov     bh, 0
mov     cx, 6
mov     ah, 09h
int     10h

inc     bl 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  


mov     dl, 1  ; ******* column position.
mov     dh, 4   ; row position.
mov     ah, 02h
int     10h     


mov     bh, 0
mov     cx, 7      ;
mov     ah, 09h
int     10h

inc     bl    




je      next_row
jmp     next_char

stop_print:


mov     dl, 10  ; column.
mov     dh, 5   ; row.
mov     ah, 02h
int     10h




mov ah, 0
int 16h


ret
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're asking to simplify this sequence

```
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*'
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h    
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h   
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h 
mov dl, '*' 
int 21h
```

A simple loop will do the job

```
push cx
mov cx,7
again:
mov dl,'*'
int 21h
loop again
pop cx
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll try that later, will it form a triangle?
My code is able to change its color consecutively.